# How to set multiple values to a single variable in .json file using cypress?

Tags: javascript, json, cypress

Here is my code to write fetched values in the .json file.

```
cy.readFile(filename).then((product) => {
                    for (var i = 1; i < lens; i++) {
                        cy.xpath('/html/body/app-root/div/mat-sidenav-container/mat-sidenav-content/app-configurable-product/div[1]/mat-table/mat-row[' + i + ']/mat-cell[2]').then((txt) => {
                            var namee = txt.text()
                            cy.log(namee)
                            product.product_name = namee
                            cy.writeFile(filename, product, {flag: 'a+'})
                        })
                    }
            })
```

I want to get data in the below .json format.

{
"product_name": [" Jam & Honey Girl's Regular Fit T-Shirt ", " Kids hoodie ", " Women tank top "]
}

Comment: What does this print `cy.log(namee)` ? And what are the contents of the `product ` file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps use each instead of for loop

```js
cy.readFile(filename).then((product) => {

  if (!product.product_name) product.product_name = [] // initial

  cy.xpath('/html/body/app-root/div/mat-sidenav-container/mat-sidenav-content/app-configurable-product/div[1]/mat-table/mat-row')
    .each($row => {
      cy.wrap($row).find('mat-cell').eq(2).invoke('text')
        .then(text => {
          product.product_name.push(text)
        })
    })
    .then(() => {
      cy.writeFile(filename, product)
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select multiple rows and and convert them to array of texts

```js
cy.xpath('/html/body/app-root/div/mat-sidenav-container/mat-sidenav-content/app-configurable-product/div[1]/mat-table/mat-row')
  .find('mat-cell').eq(2)
  .then($cells => {
    const texts = [...$cells].map(cell => cell.innerText)  // array of texts
    cy.readFile(filename).then((product) => {
      product.product_name = texts
      cy.writeFile(filename, product)
    })
  })
```